# What is the maximum possible value range of MATCH ('...' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, relevance, match-against

MySQL provides `FULLTEXT` indexes, that can be retrieved with the [`MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) construct. There are several [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en//fulltext-search.html) variants, one of them (and the default one) is the [Natural Language Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en//fulltext-natural-language.html).

So what is the maximal possible value of the MATCH ('...'  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)?

---

Example:

This query

```
SELECT
    courses.id,
    courses.title,
    MATCH (coursedata.title) AGAINST ('Basketball') AS relevance
FROM
    courses
JOIN
    coursedata ON coursedata.id = courses.coursedata_id
WHERE
    MATCH (coursedata.title) AGAINST ('Basketball') > 0
```

returns a result table with column `relevance`, where we're storing the relevance value of `coursedata.title` rows for `'Basketball'`. Or the relevance value of `'Basketball'` for `coursedata.title` rows? Anyway, we're storing there the output of the `MATCH(...)` function. In my case I'm geting values from `0` to `3.695953130722046`.

Comment: You may have a real question here, but as it stands the question is too vague to be addressed. Consider editing it to more clearly ask a specific question.

Comment: Every couple of years I try to Google the answer to this and I never get anywhere. My guess is that there is no theoretical maximum, since it is generally related to the number of matches found, as well as the length of the column(s) being searched and the length of the search expression. It's too bad, because if it was guaranteed to be between 0 and 100 (with 100 being a perfect match) then the number would be meaningful on an absolute scale.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a small limit for the possibilities of your query output. So instead of reaching that huge limit, you will freeze down your MySQL / your network.